# Spin orientations

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-spin

The concept of spin is purely a quantum mechanical effect, it is restricted to given values in given orientations. If hypothetically spin were a classical concept yet still of a fixed value, would its orientation be quantised too?

As a chemist I am focused towards the nuclear spin quantum number $I$. The loss of degeneracy in the presence of a magnetic field leads to nuclear spin states for each orientation where $I\neq 0$. If there were no restriction on the orientation of a given spin then would there be a continuum of levels in a classical system (of discrete spins)? This could make sense in the classical limit since the energy separation between adjacent states is given by $\gamma \hbar B_0$.

Sorry if it seems a bit of a "null" question.

Comment: Could you try and clarify what you are asking? "...if spin were a classical concept yet still of a fixed value..." What do you mean? You can have a fixed value magnetic momentum in classical physics, for example, and its values along any axis are not quantized... Also, the words "quantized" and "discrete" mean the same thing. Are you using them in a different sense?

Answer (score 1):

No, if the spin were classical, as any classical angular momentum it **weren't quantized**. It's easier to take as an example the orbital angular momentum. It is quantized because of *the wave-nature of the quantum particle*.

To put it in an intuitive form, not every function can represent the wave-function of the electron in the atom. Imagine an oscillating rope: some frequencies of waves are allowed and form standing waves, other frequencies aren't fit and are destroyed by destructive interference. The same with the allowed wave-functions.

Exactly as the frequencies of a rope are discrete, the values of the energy in an atom, of the orbital momentum, of the magnetic momentum, all these are discrete.

A classical gyroscope doesn't need a wave-description, and don't have this limitation.

The same with the nuclear spin, and magnetic moment.

About *restriction of orientation*, which restriction? When we place a nucleus in a magnetic field, the nucleus doesn't have a prior orientation of the spin, unless you performed previously a Stern-Gerlach type of measurement and delected a certain orientation of the spin. And again, this has nothing to do with quantization - if your nucleus is $z$-oriented by spin, in a $x$-oriented magnetic field you'll have different $x$-projection of the spin, and discrete.

In the classical limit $\hbar \to 0$, this is why you get a continuum of magnetic levels. But in the limit $\hbar \to 0$ the de Broglie wavelength $\lambda = h/mv$ becomes zero, the wavelike description of an object doesn't remain anymore in vigor.